# Connecting an ADC to external input

Tags: adc

I have a 12-bit resolution high speed pipelined ADC on [PIC24FJ128GC010](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30009312b.pdf) micro-controller. It has an internal input [from an another peripheral internal to the chip]. Now, I would like to add another analog input to the ADC externally [to one of the ANx pins]. Can I achieve this with very little noise? What care must be taken in this case?

Comment: ... what?  "Internal input"? Eh?

Comment: I MEAN... The ADC has an input from another peripheral within the PIC controller.

Comment: Ok.  So - you connect your signal to one of the analog pins and instruct the ADC to read from it.

Comment: As long as you have decent decoupling of the analog supply pins, and your reference voltage is stable and clean, then it's all down to how you supply your mystery analog signal.